# What is the best way to redirect to a model with its own unique template?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a league that will be made up of individual teams which are represented by a team model. What I want to do is list the teams on the league homepage(base.html) and have each team be a link to their respective page which is represented by a different template that extends base.html. What is the best strategy for achieving this? I can make it work if I write each team link one by one I guess, but I'm running into trouble if I try to use a for loop in the base.html template. Is it possible to have a template attribute in a model where I save the template and somehow redirect to that attribute?

```
 # Team
 class Team(models.Model):
team_choices = TEAM_CHOICES
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, choices=team_choices)
players = models.ManyToManyField('accounts.User', related_name='players', blank=True)
season = models.ManyToManyField('Season', related_name='team_seasons', blank=True)
city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
sponsor = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
about = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
credits = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
url = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images')
video = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='videos')
date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['name', 'neighborhood', 'sponsor', 'about', 'credits']

def create(self):
    self.created_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def __getitem__(self,index):
    return self.name[index]

def __setitem__(self,index,value):
    self.name[index] = value
```

These are relevant views I'm working with:

```
 class League(generic.ListView):
     model = Team
     template_name = 'league.html'

     def get_queryset(self):
         t = Team.objects.filter()
         return t

 def team1(request):
    team = Team.objects.get(name='team1')
    return render(request, 'team/team1.html', {'team':team,})
    print (team.name)

 class team_redirect(View):
    template_name = 'home/base.html'
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(reverse('Get_team', args=(team.name,)))

 class Get_team(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
     Model = Team

     def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
         team = get_object_or_404(Team, name=self.kwargs['name'])
         return team
```

I want to have the link in the template redirect to the specific teams homepage and template, but this is where I'm running into trouble. Difficulty passing the right kwargs to the urls.

```
 #Urls
    url(r'^league$', views.League.as_view(), name='league'),

           # Team Redirect
           url(r'^team_redirect$', views.team_redirect.as_view(), name='team_redirect'),

           # Get Team
           url(r'^team/(?P<team_name>\d+)/view$', views.Get_team.as_view(), name='get_team'),
```

Comment: You `__setattr__` will most likely fail, since a string is immutable, so you can not change  a character.

Comment: You can override the `get_template_names()` method of your class based view, to change the template used at runtime. This method is called after `get_object()`, so you can access `self.object` in this method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. Both helpful answers.